# How to install the etsproxy package?

Tags: python-2.7

Please help me to resolve this issue about the install of the etsproxy
This is an error when running command below:

> sudo easy_install etsproxy
>
> Searching for etsproxy
>
> Reading https://pypi.python.org/simple/etsproxy/
>
> No local packages or download links found for etsproxy
>
> error: Could not find suitable distribution for Requirement.parse('etsproxy')

Answer (score 1):

Did u try install by pip?

pip install -U etsproxy

https://pypi.org/project/etsproxy/

Comment: I tried with your guide but there is an error:
> pip install -U etsproxy

> Collecting etsproxy

> Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement etsproxy (from versions: )

> No matching distribution found for etsproxy

Comment: I also try with other command: pip install -U etsproxy https://pypi.org/project/etsproxy/ >  Collecting https://pypi.org/project/etsproxy/ > Downloading > Cannot unpack file /tmp/pip-unpack-_ixbQ0/etsproxy (downloaded from /tmp/pip-req-build-SeN4u8, content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8); cannot detect archive format > Cannot determine archive format of /tmp/pip-req-build-SeN4u8

Comment: You can clone the project and exec the command; python setup.py install. It's another approach. https://github.com/enthought/etsproxy